# Simplify algebraic expression $U=yz^2-xz$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R},$ such that $x=\sqrt{y^4}, \ z=\sqrt{y^2},$ and $U=yz^2-xz,$ then which statement is true for all real numbers $y$?

a) $U=0$

b) $U=\pm2y^3$

c) $U=y^3-|y|^3$

d) None of the above

**Attempt:** This means that $$\begin{array}{lcl}
x & = & \sqrt{y^2\cdot y^2} & = & \sqrt{y^2}\cdot\sqrt{y^2} & = & |y|\cdot|y| & 
= & |y|^2 \\
z & = & \sqrt{y^2} & =  &|y| \\
 & \text{so, } & \\
U & = & y\cdot|y|^2-|y|^2\cdot y & = & 0
\end{array}$$

To my great disapointment, this is not correct. It seems as if $z^2=\left(\sqrt{y^2}\right)^2=y^2$ is used instead of $z^2=|y|^2.$ Why?

Answer (score 1):

> $U = y\cdot|y|^2-|y|^2\cdot y$

Based on the above $x=y^2$ and $z=|y|$, this should be $\,U=yz^2-xz=y^3-y^2 |y|\,$ instead. Since $y^2=|y|^2$ this can also be written as $U=y^3-|y|^3$.

> To my great disapointment, this is not correct. It seems as if $z^2=\left(\sqrt{y^2}\right)^2=y^2$ is used instead of $z^2=|y|^2.$

Note that $\,|y|^2=y^2\,$ for all real $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}\,$, so that's not the problem here. Issue is that you mistakenly substituted $z=y$ instead of $z=|y|$ in the second term.

Comment: Why isn't $x=|y|^2$?

Comment: @Parseval $|a|\,|b|=|ab|$ and $\,y^2 \ge 0\,$ for $\forall a,b,y \in \mathbb{R}\,$, so $|y|^2=|y|\,|y|=|y^2| = y^2$

Answer (score 0):

$x=\sqrt{y^4}, \ z=\sqrt{y^2}$, thus $x=|y^2|=y^2, z=|y|$

$$U=yz^2-xz=y\times |y|^2 - y^2\times |y|=y\times y^2 - |y|^2 \times |y|^3$$

$$=y^3-|y|^3$$

Comment: Why isn't $x=|y|^2$?

Comment: @Parseval as of a result, it is true that $x=|y|^2$, but logically, it's better that we view $x=\sqrt{y^4}=\sqrt{z^2}$, where $z=y^2$, and $x=|z|$

Comment: But if it is true, then my answer should not be wrong. So since my answer is wrong, it's clearly not true that $x=|y|^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Parseval The problem with your answer is not in the $|y|^2$ part, it is that the last $\color{red}{y}$ in $U = y\cdot|y|^2-|y|^2\cdot \color{red}{y}$ should have been $\color{red}{|y|}\,$ since $z=|y|\,$.

Comment: @Parseval, firstly the notation $z$ I used in my comment is not the one in your question - I just grab a variable other than $y$. $x=\sqrt{y^4}=\sqrt{w^2}$, where $w=y^2$, and $x=|w|$. And in your answer, you did almost correctly, except that you should have $z=|y|$, but not $z=y$ for the last $z$ in the equation that you try to substitute.

Comment: Yes but then I'd get $U=y|y|^2-|y|^3,$ which is still the incorrect answer.

Comment: @Parseval yes, you are correct. And then notice that $|y|^2 = y^2$

Comment: So, if an absolute value is raised to an even power, it is equal to whatever is contained in it, but if it's raised to an odd power, it si not equal to whatever is contained in it? If $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $|a|^{2k+1}\neq z^2$ but  $|a|^{2k} = |a|^2?$

Comment: @Parseval Yes you are right. And can you see why? $|y|$ v.s. $y$, they are at most off by a sign if $y$ is negative, and they are the same if $y$ is positive. So if $y \ge 0$, $|y| = y$, and $|y|^2 = y^2$; if $y <0$, then $|y|=-y$, and $|y|^2 = (-y)^2=y^2$ - thus it is the same when $k$ is even.